# Paste table from Excel and put body text into Outlook email

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want both body text and a table from Excel to appear in one email.

```vb
Sub SendEmailA()
    Dim outlookApp As Object
    Dim mailItem As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dataRange As Range
    Dim dateValue As String
    Dim excelFilePath As String
    Dim emailTitle As String
    Dim emailBody1 As String
    
    excelFilePath = "Assuming Shipping Plan File.xlsm"
    Set ws = Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath).Sheets("Shipping Plan")
    dateValue = Format(ws.Range("B1").Value, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    Set dataRange = ws.Range("B4:F18")
    If ws.Range("B2").Value = "Jefferson GA" Then
        Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set mailItem = outlookApp.CreateItem(0)
        mailItem.To = "example@example.com"
        emailTitle = "For " & Format(ws.Range("B1").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") & " **FTL Transfer Request **"
        emailBody1 = "Hi"
        ' Add email details
        With mailItem
            .Subject = emailTitle
            dataRange.Copy
            .HTMLBody = "<br><br>" & emailBody1 & "<br><br>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " "
            .Display ' Change to .Send if you want to send without preview
        End With
        
        ' Release objects
        Set outlookApp = Nothing
        Set mailItem = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

I can't get both the body text and the table from Excel to appear in one email.

I also tried to write this in Python and encountered the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...

```
With MailItem
    .Display
    .Subject = emailTitle
    DataRange.Copy
    .HTMLBody = "<p>" & emailBody1 & "</p><br>"
    With .GetInspector.WordEditor
        .Application.Selection.EndKey Unit:=6 'wdStory
        .Application.Selection.TypeParagraph
        .Application.Selection.Paste
    End With
    .HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<p>" & emailBody2 & "</p>"
    '.Send 'uncomment to send email
End With
```

Note that WordEditor represents the Microsoft Word Document Object Model for the email being displayed, and Selection represents the insertion point in the email.

Also, note that the email needs to be displayed before being able to use the Selection property of the WordEditor.

Comment: This worked, Thank you so much! 

But I have a couple of follow up questions. 

1. Can you please explain what the Selection property of the WordEditor does?

2. How would I write the code if I want to add another body "emailBody2" after the table is pasted?

Comment: I have amended my post accordingly.